# Resource (.resx) files with multiple values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resource-files

I was wondering if can create some resource file which represents multiple values per key.

any suggestion?

Thank You;

Comment: I want a dictionary with two values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding Properties.Settings add the variable of type System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary in it add 2 items and save it

a setting variable can be scoped to be used at application or user level

Please example here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C